# JOIN Query while loading comments

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm loading comments for product with id = '3'

```
$get_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  products_comments WHERE product_id = '3'");
```

Now I want to add the "report abuse" option for each comment, for this purpose I'm having another table as "`abuse_reports`" which user abuse reports will be stored in this table, now if a user reported a comment, the `report abuse` option should not be there for that comment for that user there anymore, for this I'm doing:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_comments)){
   echo blah blah blah // comment details
   // now for checking if this user should be able to report this or not, i make this query again:
   $check_report_status = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM abuse_reports WHERE reporter_user_id = '$this_user_id' AND product_id = 'this_product_id'");
   // blah blah count the abuse reports which the current user made for this product
   if($count == 0) echo "<a>report abuse</a>";
}
```

With the above code, for each comment I'm making a new query, and that's obviously wrong, how I should join the second query with the first one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated query (that is working now, commited by questioner)**

```
SELECT pc. * , count( ar.`id` ) AS `abuse_count`
FROM `products_comments` pc
LEFT OUTER JOIN `abuse_reports` ar ON pc.`id` = ar.`section_details`
AND ar.`reporter_id` = '$user_id'
WHERE pc.`product_id` = '$product_id'
GROUP BY pc.`id`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The query works as follow: You select all the fields of your `products_comments` with the given `product_id` but you also count the entries of `abuse_reports` for the given `product_id`. Now you `LEFT JOIN` the `abuse_reports`, which means that you access that table and hang it on to the left (your products_comments table). The OUTER allows that there is no need for a value in the abuse_reports table, so if there is no report you get null, and therefore a count of 0.

**Please read this:**
However, I needed to group the results, otherwise you get only one merged row as result. So please extend your `products_comments` with a field `comment_id` of type `int` that is the `primary key` and has `auto_increment`.

**UPDATE: abuse count**
Now you can do two things: By looping through the results, you can see for each single element if it has been reported by that user or not (that way you can hide abuse report links for example). If you want the overall number of reports, you just increase a counter variable which you declare outside the loop. Like this:

```
$abuse_counter = 0;
while($row = mysql....)
{
  $abuse_counter += intval($row['abuse_count']);   // this is 1 or 0
  // do whatever else with that result row
}

echo 'The amount of reports: '.$abuse_counter;
```

Just a primitive sample

Comment: this doesn't load any of comments for product_id = 3

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated the query in my answer above - it works now, I tested it on my own. It was a mistake in the `WHERE` clause, as the `reporter_user_id` might not be always available (so it had to be in the `ON` part). Hope it works for you now, please let me know ;)

Comment: there seem to be something wrong, it just loads 1 comment while there is more than 10 comment for product_id = 3, and for other products it loads nothing!

Comment: the result should be all the comments for product_id = 3, and also having access to number of report abuses submitted for this product by this user

Comment: Edited my answer at top once again, please consider the last paragraph to make that query working. I think that is now what you were expecting. And tested this in the scenario you have told (with 0 and multiple reports and 1 to multiple comments).

Comment: I already have the AU id col for products_comments, let me check this, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Alright, and I edited my answer on top again (see last "UPDATE abuse count"), so you know how I mean to use it :)

Comment: `echo $row['abuse_count']` always prints 0 while some of the comments are reported, so the `report abuse` link is still there... :-(

Comment: Could you do a `print_r();` on $get_commands? And how does your final query looks like (with your adapted naming and variables) - must be a small issue, we will fix that :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32556/discussion-between-behz4d-and-francodi)

Comment: this is my final query: `$get_comments = mysql_query("SELECT pc.*, count(ar.`id`) AS `abuse_count` FROM `products_comments` pc
LEFT OUTER JOIN `abuse_reports` ar ON pc.`product_id` = ar.`product_id` AND ar.`reporter_id` = ".$user_id." WHERE pc.`product_id` = '$product_id'
GROUP BY pc.`id`")or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: and `echo $row['abuse_count']`  will always print 0, my query is exactly what you told...

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't sure if I should have mentioned it and thought you would see it yourself, I forgot the name of your variable and wrote it in my own database, so I wrote `$user_id`, but you named it `$this_user_id` - so you are always executing with a not-existing variable :) Just change it back to yours.

Comment: But I already saw it, it is `$user_id = $this_user_id;`, so this is not the problem...

Comment: Alright, edited the answer if someone else ever needs the solution. So everything seems to be working fine, if you're facing any issue with it simply invite me to the chat again :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for a query something like this.

```
SELECT pc.*, COUNT(ar.*) 
FROM  products_comments AS pc
LEFT JOIN abuse_reports AS ar ON reporter_user_id = pc.user_id AND ar.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE product_id = '3'"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL

```
 SELECT pc.*, COUNT(ar.id) AS abuse_count
 FROM  products_comments pc
      LEFT JOIN abuse_reports ar ON pc.product_id = ar.product_id
 WHERE pc.product_id = '3' AND ar.reporter_user_id = '$this_user_id'
 GROUP BY pc.product_id
```

The result is list of products_comments with abuse_reports count if exist for reporter_user_id

Comment: the result should be all the comments for product_id = 3, and also having access to number of report abuses submitted for this product by this user, this is not working...